# OBS Stubio 0.16.2 doesn't have a game capture source

Tags: obs-studio

I recently downloaded OBS Studio through Terminal, and the sources list does not have Game Capture a s an option. is that an issue with my copy, or just with the linux release in general? In case it's the former, how can I fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This option exists on OBS for Windows but not on Linux while Nvidia doesn't want. Game capture option for OBS need Geforce Experience and that doesn't exists on Linux.